Is this question about automation appropriate for SuperUser?
I'm working on a data cleaning automation task.
Every month we receive an e-mail from a specific client with two folders with PDF files attached.
My goal is to find a way to download these folders, rename them and move them to a specific folder that's connected to PowerQuery. The later steps are already taken care of.
I've researched for solutions online, but they work rather as 'single-use' workarounds and I thought that maybe the community could give me pointers on more consistent and solid and ways to use cmd in an automated way.

Have you not asked your question yet, or was it deleted?

@HashimAziz I haven't yet had the opportunity to post my question.

SuperUser is not a free script/code writing service.
If your question tells us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck, then we can try to help with specific problems.
Please also read How do I ask a good question? - Help Center - Super User
